# How to update combobox after new data added to LocalDB

Tags: c#, sql, data-binding, combobox, localdb

I'm loading combobox items from LocalDB using Data Binding without any coding. [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VlKUR.jpg)

I'm Inserting new item_name using below code.

```
using (SqlConnection myConn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    myConn.Open();

    string Query = "INSERT INTO items (item_name, generic) VALUES ('" + NewItemNameBox.Text + "', '" + SelectGenericNewItemBox.Text + "');";
    using (SqlCommand SQLcmd = new SqlCommand(Query, myConn))
    {
        SQLcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    myConn.Close();

}
```

Code is working. My problem is after adding new item to DB, combobox does not update. I need to show newly added item names in combobox. It is working when I reopen my app. How to do it without re opening? Like using a Button...

Comment: Try doing `BindingSource.ResetBindings(true)`

Comment: Thanks for help. This code do it for me. `this.itemsTableAdapter.Fill(this.mainDBDataSet.items);`

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Comment: Dear @mark_s appreciate your warning. I'm using this app on local PC

Answer (score 0):

This code do it for me.
`this.itemsTableAdapter.Fill(this.mainDBDataSet.items);`